# Non Cluster indexes on multiple columns VS multiple columns in a single index

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am in a process of adding non clustered indexes to SQL Azure DB and I wonder what is the difference between having multiple columns in a single non clustered index, compared to having multiple non clustered indexes with each having a single column in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the difference between having multiple columns in a single non clustered index, compared to having multiple non clustered indexes with each having a single column in it?

Consider a table `T` with a clucstered PK `Id` column, and additionally columns `A`, `B`, `C`.

A single nonclustered index containing `A`, `B`, and `C` could support fast lookup for queries such as:

```
WHERE A > @a
WHERE A = @a AND @b1 < B AND B < @b2
WHERE A = @a AND B = @b AND C < @c
```

but not

```
WHERE B = @b
WHERE C = @c
```

in both of which cases, we can't do any better than a table scan

However, if we have multiple indexes, `IX_A` on `A`, etc:

```
WHERE A = @a
WHERE B = @b
WHERE C = @c
```

would all benefit from an index, and a composite query such as

```
WHERE A = @a AND B = @b AND C < @c
```

would have a small benefit too.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` query those will optimize are different.

You shouldn't be adding index without a need for query performance optimization.

If you have a query to optimize, then you can start thinking about adding indexes corresponding to the query you want to optimize.

Let's say you have a table containing the following structure :

```
create table emp
(
    id int identity primary key clustered,
    name nvarchar(200),
    dep_id int,
    salary int
);
```

Your clustered index (the `primary key clustered` clause) will speed up look-up and row data retrieval for queries using the `id` column as filter like :

```
select id, name, dep_id, salary
from emp
where id = @id
```

Any non clustered index on any (unique) column will speed the look-up (not the row data retrieval) using the same column as a filter.

```
create index emp_name_idx on emp(name);
-- will speed up look-up for 
select id, dep_id
from emp
where name = @name
```

If you also want to speed up the row data retrieval using the same index, you will need to add the columns present in the `SELECT` clause to the included columns.

```
create index emp_name_idx on emp(name) include(id, dep_id);
-- will speed up look-up and data row retrieval for 
select id, dep_id
from emp
where name = @name
```

Any non clustered index containing multiples columns will speed up look-up for queries using the first n columns in the same order as they appear in the index (as long as the filters are equality comparison, the column optimization streak will end as the first inequality comparison is met).

```
create index emp_namesalary_idx on emp(dep_id, salary);
-- will speed up look-up and data row retrieval for 
select id, dep_id
from emp
where dep_id = @dep_id
  and salary > @salary
```

As for the single column indexes, to also optimize row data retrieval, use the `include` clause to specify every columns in the `SELECT` clause that is not already present in the index columns list.

Remember that for every index you add to a table, you are also adding `INSERT` overhead for this table. So you should always balance performance between gains from the index on `SELECT` statement and losses on the `INSERT` ones.
Remember also that indexes use disk (and cache) space and that should also count in the decision process.

Comment: I have a ton of queries each doing something else.

Comment: Then you can optimize each one of those, or preferably only the resource intensive ones, depending on your insertion performance needs. And if you want advice on which index will speed up which query, you should start to read basics on indexing. I'll update the answer to give a simple example.